# Installing wordpress on a subdomain of an already existing static website

Tags: plugins, installation, subdomains

I've been installing wordpress on a subdomain of an already existing static website `www.example.com` for my friend. I have installed it correctly on a subdomain `www.sub.example.com`, then he asked me to install some custom plugin of his another friends making. I wasn't able to install it through a panel and when I uploaded it to `plugins` file through ftp it was not visible in the panel, so I suggested him that there might be something wrong with the plugin.

Today he contacted me and said, that he has called (so he cannot copy paste me the conversation) tech uspport of the website host (godaddy) and suppousedly they told him that wordpress cannot be installed on a subdomain of an already exisiting static website, because there might be some code confilcts. I'm sure I have installed it correctly as I have done it many times before, also on subdomains, but I'm no expert on serwer side issues.

**QUESTION**

Is this true that I can't install wordpress on a subdomain, if there is a static website on a main domain? If it's true, are there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO..

By static i think you mean a standard (simple) HTML site.

> wordpress cannot be installed on a subdomain of an already exisiting
>   static website, because there might be some code confilcts.

That's ridiculous....

I can't imagine GoDaddy gave this answer, contact them yourself.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Thanks, yes I mean html and css only website. I am suspecting that my friend is trying to make do more work for him by coming up with this. I also found that to be ridiculous at first but needed confirmation, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code conflicts they are referring to is the server directives. A possible workaround, you may be able to get it to work by defining multiple `VirtualHost` directives on your server and ensuring your hosting environment matches your directory structure.
I can't think of any other "code conflict" that could happen (at least with WP - plugins may be a different story) so long as WordPress knows where it's `DocumentRoot` is, it should run just fine.

**Example:**

```html
<!-- Root of your website -->
<VirtualHost *:80>     DocumentRoot "~/www/html/" </VirtualHost>
<!-- Root of subdomain. Install WordPress here -->
<VirtualHost *:80>     DocumentRoot "~/www/html/subdomain/" </VirtualHost>
```